# Google foobar biggest number % 3

Tags: java

Google gave me a challenge to:

> You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function
> solution(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some
> or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. If it is not possible to
> make such a number, return 0 as the solution. L will contain anywhere
> from 1 to 9 digits. The same digit may appear multiple times in the
> list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

so I came up with the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Solution {
    public static int solution(int[] l ) {
        ArrayList<Integer> usable = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> mod1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> mod2 = new ArrayList<>();
        // sort given numbers by mod 3
        for (int i:l){
            if (i % 3 == 0) usable.add(i);
            else if (i % 3 == 1) mod1.add(i);
            else mod2.add(i);
        }
        // add groups of 3 numbers that mod 3
        while (mod1.size() >= 3){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) usable.add(mod1.remove(0));
        }
        while (mod2.size() >= 3){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) usable.add(mod2.remove(0));
        }
        // mod1 + mod2 == mod3
        while (mod1.size() != 0 && mod2.size() !=0){
            usable.add(mod1.remove(0));
            usable.add(mod2.remove(0));
        }
        // if no usable elements i.e. {2,8}
        if (usable.size() == 0) return 0;
        // sort usable elements
        Collections.sort(usable);
        Collections.reverse(usable);
        // convert arr into a number
        int ans = 0;
        for (int i: usable) {
            ans = ans*10 + i;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

This is working for most of Googles tests but it's failing the 4th test. Can someone tell me where my code goes wrong?

Comment: What's your thought process? How did you come up with this and where do you think the problem might be? What edge cases have you considered, and do you handle them correctly? In an interview it's important not just to come up with some code but to explain your thinking and your debugging process, so let's practice that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various issues with this code.

Let's say as input, you have `44477`. Your code will toss all of these digits into the `mod1` bucket. It then takes the first 3 elements from that bucket (`444`) and treats them as usable digits.

The 77 remains unused. And therein lies your error; it's better to take 774 instead of 444.

**First problem**: Sort the `mod1` and `mod2` buckets, highest numbers first, *before* fetching digits out.

Second problem: You have forced the output to be an `int`, however, in java, ints are defined as taking exactly 32-bits worth of storage, meaning, they can only represent all numbers between and including `[-2^31, +2^31-1]`. `int` has defined behaviour if you attempt to exceed this: The numbers 'wrap around'. You can observe this in action:

```
int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // constant representing 2^31 -1
System.out.println(x);
x = x + 1;
System.out.println(x);
```

If you run that, you'll see the second print statement actually prints a very large negative number (in fact, the 'biggest' negative number: -2^31), because the `+1` operation caused the int to wrap around (the technical term is "overflow"). I don't know how the problem works, but assuming that the input digit list can contain more than 9 digits, that's a problem - `int` is not big enough. There is no reason to mess with int here. Don't convert back to int *at all*. Just print the digits in your `usable` arraylist one by one without spaces. If you have a list containing `[9, 9, 7, 4, 1]`, then print each element individually using `System.out.print`, which would produce the output `99741` which is what you want. And it won't ever use `int` which is risky, what with the overflow issue.

If the problem description explicitly requires you to return an `int` value, then this isn't a problem, I guess. However, that means the problem is broken as written if the input can contain more than 9 digits. (because e.g. 3333333333 - that's ten threes, **does not fit in an `int`**, and therefore cannot possibly by returned by this function no matter what you do, at least, until you change what it returns. `long` gets you a few more digits, but to support any length, you have to return a `String`, or just send it to the file or standard out or wherever the answer is supposed to go straight from the function.

There may be more issues than these 2, of course.